# PSU for GTX 970 + i7 4790

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

For my new PC I'm currently looking at getting an Intel i7 4790 (non "k" version) and a GTX 970 as the main components for the system. It will also be running an SSD, HDD, Network card, and 32GB of RAM. I've highlighted the two main components of the system, because, as it stands, the combined TDP of both the CPU and GPU is 684W (Gigabyte on the GPU side). I understand that TDP doesn't necessarily relate to the actual wattage draw of the component, however a page reviewing several GPUs (including the 970, [here](http://www.anandtech.com/show/8568/the-geforce-gtx-970-review-feat-evga)) details the 970s TDP at only 145W, which would make the combined TDP of the two main components at 229W - so:

a) Why do manufacturers state the TDP so much higher than what reviews state?

b) I was looking at getting a 750W 80+ Gold Modular PSU from Corsair, but after looking into this further, I contemplated getting a 450W PSU instead. Would I get away with doing so?

Comment: People are voting to close this question as hardware recommendation. I think they are mistaken. The OP is asking about hardware requirements rather than specific hardware choices.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton If it's not a hardware recommendation then it it is opinion based (Why do manufacturers state?, Would I get away with doing so?) - also off topic.

Comment: @DavidPostill Closed after I posted to the Meta Tavern.

Comment: @cybermonkey url for meta tavern?

Comment: @DavidPostill http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3545528#3545528

Answer (score 4):

Go with the 750 watt power supply. It will be able to handle your system. I had a 500 watt power supply before and had issues with the computer shutting down due to high load from the graphics card when I upgraded to an i7 CPU and 970GTX graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

A) The TDP that comes from the manufacturer is measured at peak performance with a higher than normal ambient temperature. That means when they measure the TDP, the graphics card has probably been running at or close to 100% for a few minutes. This is hardly ever the case when gaming and you might see your graphics card average 40-60% usage during your gaming. This will obviously vary depending on what games you play. Same works for the CPU. The TDP is measured at 100% usage. If your CPU hits 100% usage then something is wrong.

B) Yes, a 750w power supply would be overkill. A 600-660w power supply would be enough. That being said I would still get the 750w power supply because it's a corsair (great brand) and because it will help you future proof your machine.

Answer (score 1):

450W is plenty for this combination if you don't plan to add another GPU or a large RAID-Array in the future. I have recently built a very similar setup with a i7-4790k, a GTX-970, 32 GB DDR-3 2400 RAM, a m2 SSD and 6 fans on a ASUS Z97-Deluxe Board. The CPU is overclocked to 4x 4.5 GHz (~1.25V) and I run it with a 450W 80+ Gold PSU (the cute little SFX device from Silverstone). I measured the system with a power meter and it draws up to 430W from the wall socket when I run Prime64 and Furmark simultaneously. With full CPU load alone it needs approximately 280W. I think a non overclocked CPU might need at least 70W less. You should calculate with at least 10W per mechanical hard disk or optical drive and at least 5W for every extra SSD or fan.

The power rating of a PSU refers to a combined power scenario of all voltages it can deliver. This may not be the combination that your system needs. A typical system with current components consumes almost all it's power from the 12V supply, so you should look for a PSU that can deliver a sufficiently high output at 12V alone already. I.e. my PSU is rated at 36A on 12V, so it will be fine at least up to 480W when measured at the wall socket (36A*12V*0.90). The 0.90 factor accounts for the 90% efficiency at full load.

Some PSUs still use a multi-rail 12V design which can be problematic as it drastically limits the 12V supply to individual components, and I would recommend to look for a single rail PSU instead. Single rail PSUs have only one 12V power rating, i.e. 36A, while multi-rail PSUs are usually rated as 18A+18A or 2x18A or similar. I actually tried to set up this board and the CPU with a older 750W quad-rail PSU (4x14A) at first and I didn't get it stable with overclocking while it was no problem when I connected it to the 450W single rail PSU.

I would recommend not to use a much more powerful than needed PSU if you already know that you will not even need that much power in the future. Not only are lower rated PSUs typically less expensive but they are actually more efficient at typical idle loads since the 80+ rating doesn't require a minimum efficiency below 20% load and thus the efficiency far below 20% is usually much worse than what you would expect with the given 80+ rating even for high quality PSUs. This means that a comparatively cheap 450W 80+ Bronze PSU may well draw less power from the wall socket than a much more expensive 750W Gold PSU whenever the computer is not really busy (i.e. when you only use the browser or watch a movie which should translate to 50..80W for your hardware).

Comment: A 20W ceiling is *extremely* tight.

Comment: @cybermonkey: The 430W is the input power, which translates to about 380W output for this PSU, so it's actually 70W below the rated wattage. (See [the 80+ report](http://www.plugloadsolutions.com/psu_reports/SILVERSTONE%20TECHNOLOGY_SST-ST45SF-G_ECOS%203094_450W_Report.pdf) for detailed input/output values for this PSU). Apart form that, both Furmark and Prime64 are programs that put far more stress on the GPU and CPU than actual software, so the 430W number is much higher than what this setup will ever consume during daily use even under high load.

Answer (score 1):

Please take into consideration that a power supply never delivers his main number in watts. It will be always a lower when 100% use. A 80 GOLD certified or something similar, guarantees that the power supply will deliver 80% of his number as a final wats. So If you go for a 80 Gold 450W power supply, you can safely rely on a maximum of 360W of pure power cranking out the power supply.

Since 100% use of both GPU and CPU is very very VERY unlikely, I would say you can safely run both in a 450w. Hoever I do have my PC with a 4790K and no GPU, but when I had one it was a 960GTX and I had no issues.

PCpartpicker.com let you build your system and it will give you a reference watts usage comsumption for better measuring.

I would say no one who doesnt use SLI or a VERY beffy GPU will ever need more than 450 - 500. And wattage gets lower and lower each day.

Do take into consideration that Power Supplies are designed to deliver their main number in watts. If you put a 600w supply into your system and you are using 100w most of the time, you are wasting a ton of electricity because power s. don't know how to manage loads, they are either working or not working. The only thing that changes are the electricity requirements of your system components if they are under load or not.

further analysis:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiWThqgFfI4

Comment: Your assertion that *a power supply never delivers his main number in watts* is simply not true. You can look at any of the detailed reports at the 80+ website http://www.80plus.com/ to find out what constitutes 100% load for for every PSU that is listed there. I.e. [the 450W PSU](http://www.plugloadsolutions.com/psu_reports/SILVERSTONE%20TECHNOLOGY_SST-ST45SF-G_ECOS%203094_450W_Report.pdf) that I mentioned in my answer was tested with 515.20W input wattage at 100% load and delivered 449.49W output. Actually most PSUs of decent quality can deliver at least 10% more than their rating.